# Resources$NotFoundException exception for drawable - but it does exist?

Tags: android

I'm starting to see an odd set of stack traces from the marketplace crash reports interface. I'm being told a drawable resource does not exist. The xml in question:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="13dip"
  android:layout_height="12dip"
  android:src="@drawable/foo"
  />
```

causing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.app/com.me.app.MyActivity}: 
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: 
    Error inflating class <unknown>
...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  File res/drawable-hdpi/foo.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020166
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1732)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  res/drawable-hdpi/foo.png
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:417)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1724)
```

Now "foo.png" exists in both my "drawable" and "drawable-hdpi" folders. I haven't touched either of these drawables in ages - not sure why this error started popping up? Happening on a range of devices, Droids, Nexus Ones, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should clean your project to regenerate the R.java file? This may be the issue.

Comment: Hi Egor, I did this before my last release for sure. I checked the R file and the integer values are all present. I think there's something wrong with android.

Comment: This is really bugging me. I'm noticing my newly compiled apps are having these issues. I'm beginning to think I should write my own system for this using the assets folder. Then I can have a nice hierarchy to go along with it. Also I've noticed Lint improperly marking errors.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your IDE , Eclipse? This bugs are mostly seen in Buggiclipse :) !

Comment: @user291701 Did you solved the problem? I have the same issue I tried cleaning the project, also, the fact is the it is replicable under any compilation, I tried also compilining from bitbucket source on other computer and is still happening!! :(:(

Answer (score 3):

Try by placing foo.png in other drawable folder i.e. mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi also. May be it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods :

1- If you're developing in Eclipse, try "Project Clean" from debug menu. If you're in Intellij, try to "Build" the project.

2- Delete and readd the foo.png resource. after deleting, try to regenerate the R and then readd.

3- Rename the foo.png to something else and see how it works.

4- Try deleting the R file, because it gets generated automatically and may solve your problem

As far as I know, the problem is with the R file of your project.